# Sorting an Alphanumeric value mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find the max value in a column.

Column values are,
E00004, 
A00005, 
B00011, 
H-00001, 
E2100112, 
EFQ20098, 
ESSF20003

I just want to sort the values by their number, Dont mind about the alphabets. It have to be like this, **I'm using MYSQL**

E2100112, 
ESSF20003, 
EFQ20098,
B00011,
A00005,
E00004,
H-00001

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the last 5 digits are the number:

```
select columnName from tableName
order by convert(int, right(columnName, 5)) desc
```

---

As @IkeWalker stated, the number can have an arbitrary size.
For it, you'll have to use a while cycle to check the number.

Or, you can have a function do that for you!

[Check this article!](http://ushastry.blogspot.pt/2009/10/mysql-extract-numbers-out-of-string.html)

Comment: Some of the numbers in the sample data set are longer than 5 digits. One of them is 7 digits.